# Why do these foreach and for loops create different outputs?

Tags: php, loops, for-loop, foreach

```
$value = 1234;
$number_array = str_split($value);

for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($number_array); $i++) {
  $number_array[$i] *= 10;
} 
// output: 10, 20, 30, 40. 

foreach($number_array as &$value) {
  $value *= 10;
} 
// output: 10, 20, 30, 30.
```

Can someone explain why the for loop gives the desired result, but the foreach doesn't?

Comment: Check your code, the output is the same in for the for and foreach loop

Comment: Good question - there is no output given

Comment: Please check the output shown in the question.  It should be `100, 200, 300, 400`, not `10, 20, 30, 30` !!

Answer (score 1):

Because  for loop changes the values of   `$number_array`

do like this will give same result

```
    $value = 1234;
    $number_array = str_split($value);

    foreach($number_array as $value) {
       $value *= 10;
       echo $value;
       // output: 10, 20, 30, 40.
    } 


    for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($number_array); $i++) {
      $number_array[$i] *= 10;
    } 
    // output: 10, 20, 30, 40. 
    print_r($number_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the result with `var_dump` :

```
for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($number_array); $i++) {
  $number_array[$i] *= 10;
  var_dump($number_array[$i]);
} 
// output: int(10) int(20) int(30) int(40)

foreach($number_array as &$value) {
  $value *= 10;
  var_dump($value);
} 
// output: int(100) int(200) int(300) int(400)
```

The output is different because you assigned to each variable their multiplication by 10 in the first loop and you do it again in the second.

If you call them individually with the same values, they will do the same output.

Answer (score 0):

This two loops have exactly same result if you call it separately. But in first loop you are changing **$number_array**. Before first loop it's value is [1,2,3,4] and after it is [10,20,30,40].

take a look:

```
$value = 1234;
$number_array = str_split($value);



for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($number_array); $i++) {
  $number_array[$i] *= 10;
} 

var_dump($number_array); // 10, 20, 30, 40 

foreach($number_array as &$value) {
  $value *= 10;
}
```

**P.S** if you want to get same result for each loop, change your code like that:

```
$value = 1234;
$number_array = str_split($value);



for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($number_array); $i++) {
   $x = $number_array[$i];
   $x  *= 10;

    echo $x."</br>";
} 
echo "---</br>";


foreach($number_array as &$value) {
  $value *= 10;
    echo $value."</br>";
}
```

**Note:** don't change values into array, but write them in `$x` variable and change it

Answer (score 0):

It turned out the loop I was using to create the string was causing the incorrect output because I used `$value` again in the foreach loop of the string.

```
$value = 1234;
$number_array = str_split($value);

foreach($number_array as &$value) {
  $value *= 10;
} 
foreach($number as $value) {
  $answr .= $value . " ";
} 
// $answr = 10 20 30 30
```

Once I had changed the loop to `$num` to test, the correct output was printed.

```
foreach($number as $num) {
  $answr .= $num . " ";
} //$answr: 10 20 30 40
```

An unsual quirk, that I haven't quite got my head around yet, but I'm assuming it's because `$value` was still set as a var during the second foreach loop.

Thank you for all answers and I apologise for not posting the whole code snippet and causing confusion.